# Unit-test FileSystemWatcher.Error Event

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to unit test a private method that I have attached to my FileSystemWatcher's Error event.  MSDN says that this event "occurs when the internal buffer overflows."  I've tried to cause a buffer overflow but have not been successful so far.  The FileSystemWatcher's various properties are:

```
fileWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = false;
fileWatcher.Filter = "*";
fileWatcher.NotifyFilter = (NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.Size);
```

What is the best way of raising this event for the purpose of unit-testing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt you will be able to reliably cause a buffer overflow. It will be system and configuration dependent. (It may even be load dependent). I would suggest that instead you mock the FileSystemWatcher class and trigger the mocked event yourself to test your handler.

See [Wikipedia: Mock Object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) and this [List of Mocking frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mock_object_frameworks#C.23) for some more details if you're new to the idea of mocking.

Answer (score 1):

Just added a handler for the Error event to an existing code :). I was testing the processing of the files and with 112 files (as I have from the bug i'm working on) this gets triggered each time I copy the files to the watched folder.
Each file is about 72k and I copy them using TotalCommander which I suppose does a plain iterative copy.

Unfortunately for you it all depends on the sys config & load (as simon pointed out).

Sure you can try to flush after each written byte with eventually a number of writers, but nothing can guaranty it.